# Horizontal ListView with parchment library error

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, horizontallistview

I m just trying to use [parchment](https://github.com/EmirWeb/parchment) library to add an horizontal listView but it doesn't work for me.

I followed all the instructions to add parchment as an Android library in Eclipse and it's ok for this step. The problem is that when i'm trying to add my horizontal listView in xml file  Eclipse shows the error : " **Error: String types not allowed (at 'orientation' with value 'horizontal ')"**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#ff5a5bff"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="List App"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <mobi.parchment.widget.adapterview.listview.ListView 
            xmlns:parchment="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            parchment:orientation="horizontal"
            parchment:snapPosition="start"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can you please help

Thank's a lot

Comment: do you even know RecyclerView bruh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your root tag, 
`xmlns:parchment="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`

Also your LinearLayout.TextView 60 dp centered(vertical text)may be simplified

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:parchment="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="List App"
            android:background="#ff5a5bff"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

Answer (score 0):

in documentation xmlns is: 
`xmlns:parchment="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/<YOUR PACKAGE NAME>"`
and in your code is a: 
`xmlns:parchment="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/res-auto"`
Please check this

Comment: actually "res-auto" will automatically use current package name